# Is there a way to avoid escaping javascript tags in Apache Wicket?

Tags: javascript, wicket, knockout.js

I'm trying to use KnockoutJS and the default jQuery.tmpl templating engine, and my markup is output by Apache Wicket.

I'm finding that Wicket is turning my javascript tmpl template from:

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="myTemplate">
    Hello, ${world}!
</script>
```

Into this:

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="myTemplate">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    Hello, ${world}!
    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

Which messes KnockoutJS up something awful.

Any ideas if Wicket lets you disable this kind of stuff?

Answer (score 3):

The `<!--/*--><![CDATA[/*><!--*/\n` String that's messing with KnockoutJS is defined in Wicket's [JavascriptUtils](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.wicket/wicket/1.4.4/org/apache/wicket/util/string/JavascriptUtils.java#40). Take a look at its [writeJavascript()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.wicket/wicket/1.4.4/org/apache/wicket/util/string/JavascriptUtils.java#142) method.

It will be inconditionally appending this prefix/suffix to every header contribution made by means of [HeaderResponse.renderJavascript()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.wicket/wicket/1.4.10/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/internal/HeaderResponse.java#226) or [HeaderResponse.renderOnEventJavascript()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.wicket/wicket/1.4.10/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/internal/HeaderResponse.java#306).

I've never had to change this, but this behavior seems quite invariable, Wicket doesn't seem to allow you to specify a custom HeaderResponse class for your application so you can override the use of JavascriptUtils.

How are you contributing js? Is it dynamically generated at page construction time?
If you contributed your javascript with [HeaderContributor.renderJavascriptReference()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.wicket/wicket/1.4.10/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/internal/HeaderResponse.java#203) you would probably sort this out, although this might no be suitable to you.

Not quite related, but [this discussion](http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/Inline-Javascript-comments-td2133928.html) at the Apache Wicket Users List might be indicating that the real issue here is with KnockoutJS.

Comment: Thanks for the references. My JS is actually written directly on the template. From what I gather, they're quite persistent on only outputting strict XHTML.

Comment: In retrospect, it looks like Wicket has removed <!--/*--> and now it's just /*.  https://fisheye6.atlassian.com/browse/wicket/branches/wicket-1.5.3/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/util/string/JavaScriptUtils.java?hb=true This doesn't look like a valid change to make to a template if /* is not commented like it was in 1.4.4 :( Maybe that's why jquery.tmpl may have been picking it up in my template.